# Windows 7 not sharing all shared files

Tags: windows-7, video-streaming, xbox360, xbox-video

I've been having some trouble sharing video files from my Windows 7 computer to my other devices.

I have a few videos I'd like to watch on my TV, and I'm trying to stream them from my computer to either my Xbox One or 360. However, only 2 of the 7 videos are showing up, though they're all in the public "video" folder. I've made sure the permissions on all of them are set to be shared with "everyone" with read/write access.

I've tried a couple different methods. The "play to" method will work if it's one of the two files that show up on other devices. However, if I try to "play to" any device (not just the xboxes) any of the other videos it gives me the error "failed to retrieve media information from media server."

I've also tried to stream using Skifta on my phone. It gives me the same problem. Only the two video files are showing up, none of the others.

Does anyone have any idea why this may be? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Are those two in a different codec perchance?

Comment: No, they're all in MP4 format, and the two other files play fine.

Comment: http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-360/system/audio-video-playback

Comment: Mp4 is just the container format, they could still have different encoding. Use a tool to analyze the video then check out the link Techie007 supplied.